# Single Sign On using Microsoft MDM for a LOB iOS App

Tags: ios, azure, sdk, single-sign-on, intune

Can a cross-app SSO using ADAL be attempted using the Microsoft Intune Company Portal credentials provided when a device was enrolled?

The idea is to publish an app using this portal and fetch some data from the Graph endpoints without having to re-authorize the user as the app was deployed on a MDM managed device...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No.  You can make the sign-on process relatively simple if the device is managed and you have the Microsoft Authenticator app installed - If they have already authenticated using the Authenticator app then the sign on process will open the Microsoft Authenticator app and the user simply taps their name and it will return to your app.  Your app can't get the token required to use the Graph API without performing some sort of authentication.

Comment: Thank you Paul, appreciate your help!